# IntelliJ IDEA Change default Content Root for new projects.

Tags: intellij-idea

When I create a new project in IntelliJ IDEA (on Windows), the Content Root (where the project will be stored) defaults to `C:\Users\<username>\IdeaProjects\<projectname>`

I can change the path as I create the project, but is there anyway to change the default, which I would like to be `S:\IdeaProjects\<projectname>`?

Comment: I love PyCharm but JetBrains are seriously lacking in the ease of navigation department.

Answer (score 4):

For suggesting new project's folder, IDEA uses either last projects location or one constructed by user home and IDE's name (in your case C:\Users\\IdeaProjects).

So once you've chosen your project folder to be "S:\IdeaProjects\", when creating next project IDEA will suggest this folder to you by default.

Apart from that, I do not know about a explicit setting for default project location.

Comment: Sadly, for some reason, in my version of IDEA (latest download) the Content Root default is not changing when I change the Content_root value in More Settings on the last page of the New Project dialogue (for an Android project). You mention "project folder", should I be setting this value somewhere else?

Comment: Ahh, I have just noticed the project location at the top of that dialogue page.